# Smack error : You have joined too many conferences

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

User have 20 room. ejabber *userPreference value is 50*.

Problem arrives in below case:

1. User open app then it join 20 room.
2. app kill and open app then user join 20 rooms
3. app kill and open app then user join 10

then after give error at multiUserChat.join(mucEnterConfig)

> org.jivesoftware.smack.StanzaCollector.nextResultOrThrow(StanzaCollector.java:263)
>    org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.enter(MultiUserChat.java:355)
>    org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.join(MultiUserChat.java:711)
>   get resource constraint wait. error code='500' type='wait'>:You have joined too many conferences

Answer (score 0):

You can add the **mod_muc** option **{max_user_conferences, 100}** with a different value in **ejabberd.cfg**

Comment: In the case you are using a recent ejabberd version, the file will be *ejabberd.yml* and the option would be *max_user_conferences: 100*